# 1D array to 2D array mapping

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This may sound like a homework problem, but I swear it isn't.

I'm trying to build an iterator for this 2D-array wrapper class. I figured that if I am able to solve this problem, then I can build my iterator.

I have this 1D array of 9 consecutive integers starting at 0 and ending at 8.

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

I am given two variables `horizontal_size = 3` and `vertical_size = 3`

I want to make this array into a 2D array that is `horizontal_size` by `vertical_size`. let's call them `h` and `v` for brevity.

The result that I want to generate is this:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Given the value in the 1D array, which tells me the index, Also given `h` and `v`, which are both 3 in this case. Is there a way to generate the indices on the 2D array?

For example, the first element in the 1D array is 0, which maps to `array[0][0]`. The second element is 1, which maps to `array[0][1]`

I figured out that I can get the vertical index by doing `array1d[i] mod vertical_size`.

```
           for getting the vertical index ::: th
```

0 = [0][0]     0 mod 3 = 0
1 = [0][1]     1 mod 3 = 1
2 = [0][2]     2 mod 3 = 2

3 = [1][0]     and so on...
4 = [1][1]
5 = [1][2]

6 = [2][0]
7 = [2][1]
8 = [2][2]

But I'm not sure how to get the horizontal index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The horizontal index is given by `floor(i / v)`, or as just `i/v` if your programming language implements integer division by truncation.

For example, floor(7/3) = 2, so 7 is on the row 2.

Comment: I didn't read your answer correctly the first time and I thought you said `i/h` which was an answer that I tried, but didn't turn out to be correct. I didn't even think about dividing by the `v`. Thanks!

Comment: The indexes are either i/v and i%v, or i/h and i%h, depending on how you choose them, if h=v like here you can't tell the difference

Comment: I originally had something that was 5 by 2. I just posted 3 by 3 as a simple example. The correct anaswer is floor(i/v)

Answer (score 6):

This is working solution in java. Note that `%` is `mod` function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int[] oneD = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int w = 3;
    int h = 2;
    int[][] twoD = new int[h][w];
    int[] oneDReversed = new int[oneD.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            twoD[i][j] = oneD[i*w+j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < w*h; i++) {
        oneDReversed[i] = twoD[(i / w)][(i%w)];
    }
}
```

Why the `twoD[i][j] = oneD[i*w+j]`? Because you have cycle in cycle doing "For every row `i` selet all collumns `j` and gives it to the `array[num_of_rows][num_of_columns]` by the equaliation : `row*width` + `column`.

The reserved means: The `row` is counted as rounded down `index` devide `number_of_columns`. And the `column` is the rest of deviding the same variables (mod).

Comment: I think the poster asks for the opposite direction: One single loop for iterating over a 2D-array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do in C#, I would say its the simplest and most performant way of converting between 1D and 2D arrays it does not need to do any math in the loop and it might matter if you have arrays with millions of items *(like reading and writing images)*

**C# Code:**

```
// Creates a 2D array from a 1D array
public static int[,] Array1Dto2D(int[] array1D, int width, int height)
{
    int[,] array2D = new int[width, height];
    int i = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            array2D[x, y] = array1D[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return array2D;
}

// Creates a 1D array from a 2D array
public static int[] Array2Dto1D(int[,] array2D)
{
    int width = array2D.GetLength(0);
    int height = array2D.GetLength(1);
    int[] array1D = new int[width * height];
    int i = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            array1D[i] = array2D[x, y];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return array1D;
}
```