# How can I store the location of the pixels with colour value using C#?

Tags: c#, image, list

I am making some lists that holds the colour value (0 for black and 1 for white) for each pixel across my image. My problem is when I finish each list it just gives me a single dimensional array that only has got 0s and 1s but I don’t know to which pixel it belong when I want to drew the output image.
Can anyone tell me if I can store location of the pixels as well as the colour value both at the same time in my list? Or any other alternative?

Comment: If the pixels are added to the list in order, can't you just calculate the screen position based on the element position in the list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [1D array to 2D array mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320183/1d-array-to-2d-array-mapping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering following questions:

> Can anyone tell me if I can store location of the pixels as well as
>   the colour value both at the same time in my list? Or any other
>   alternative?

If using the .NET Framework 4 or higher, you could use a Tuple to store the values. Fill tuple following way:

```
var LocXLocYColor = new Tuple<int, int, bool>(1, 1, true);
```

You could loop through all your these values, using a foreach:

```
int locx, locy;
bool color;

foreach(var itm in LocXlocYColor)
{
    locx = itm.Item1;
    locy = itm.Item2;
    color = itm.Item3;
}
```

More Tuple information: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Above code can be used, when you want to store the pixel locations seperate as integers.
Making use of a Dictionary is another way to achieve your needs:

Create a new dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Point, bool> locationColor = new Dictionary<Point, bool>();
```

Fill dictionary with location and color:

```
locationColor.Add(new Point(1, 1), true);
...
```

Loop over items in dictionary:

```
Point location;
bool color;
foreach(KeyValuePair<Point, bool> itm in locationColor)
{
    location = itm.Key;
    color = itm.Value;th entry.Value or entry.Key
}
```

If using `Point`, don't forget to include: `System.Drawing;` on top of your class.

More Point information: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<Drawing.Point, int> pixelLocations = new Diciontary<Drawing.Point, int>();
```

Will do what you want.

Edit: Unless you're not storing your locations as points. If they're not `Point`s, then just substitute `Drawing.Point` for whatever datatype you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your list to know the location of the pixels (this is assuming you know the width or height).

If the pixels were arranged so that the top row of pixels was stored, then the second, etc, you could get the locations like this (where the origin is 1,1):

```
mylist[wantedY * width - (width - wantedX - 1)]
```

Where `wantedY` is the Y-location and `wantedX` is the X-location.

If, however, the pixels are arranged by column (so that the pixels with x = 0 were taken, then x = 1, etc), you can just use:

```
mylist[wantedX * height - (height- wantedY - 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a list, use a 2-dimensional array

```
bool[,] isWhite = new bool[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];
```

and store the values at their corresponding place in this array

```
isWhite[x, y] = theColor == Color.White;
```

The location of the pixel is the location within the array. There is no need to store it separately.